# Tensorflow - NaN loss for handwriting recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, machine-learning, mnist

I am writing code for handwritten text prediction using Tensorflow. Focusing first on the MNIST dataset for digit prediction, I created a network which worked fine for this task. But when adapting the code to now recognize letters, I am getting `Nan` as loss. Could you please help me to sort this?

```
n_node_hl1 = 100
n_node_hl2 = 100
n_node_hl3 = 100
n_classes = 62
hidden_layer_1 = {'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4096, n_node_hl1])),
                    'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl1]))}
hidden_layer_2 = {'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl1, n_node_hl2])),
                    'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl2]))}
hidden_layer_3 = {'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl2, n_node_hl3])),
                    'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl3]))}
output = {'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl3, n_classes])),
            'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}


def neural_network_model(data):
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_layer_1['weight']), hidden_layer_1['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_layer_2['weight']) , hidden_layer_2['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_layer_3['weight']) , hidden_layer_3['bias'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    out = tf.matmul(l3, output['weight'])+ output['bias']
    return out

x_train, y_train = TRAIN_SIZE(2850)
x_test, y_test = TRAIN_SIZE(1900)

with tf.name_scope("MNIST_Input"):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4096], name='x')           
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 62], name='y')
y = neural_network_model(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.2
    TRAIN_STEPS = 200

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    with tf.name_scope("cross_entropy"):
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(neural_network_model(x)), reduction_indices=[1]))
    with tf.name_scope("loss_optimiser"):    
        training = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cross_entropy)
    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    tbWritwr = tf.summary.FileWriter(logpath, sess.graph)
    for i in range(TRAIN_STEPS+1):
        sess.run(training, feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train}) 
        if i%10 == 0:
            print('Training Step:' + str(i) + '  Accuracy =  ' + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test})) + '  Loss = ' + str(sess.run(cross_entropy, {x: x_train, y_: y_train})))
            # print('Training Step:' + str(i) + '  Loss = ' + str(sess.run(cross_entropy, {x: x_train, y_: y_train})))

    savedPath = tf.train.Saver().save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")

    print("Model saved at: " ,savedPath)
```

The output that i am getting is:

```
Total Training Images in Dataset = (2852, 4096)
--------------------------------------------------
x_train Examples Loaded = (2850, 4096)
y_train Examples Loaded = (2850, 62)

Total Training Images in Dataset = (2852, 4096)
--------------------------------------------------
x_train Examples Loaded = (1900, 4096)
y_train Examples Loaded = (1900, 62)

TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
Total testing Images in Dataset = (558, 4096)
--------------------------------------------------
x_test Examples Loaded = (400, 4096)
y_test Examples Loaded = (400, 62)

Training Step:0  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = nan
Training Step:10  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = nan
Training Step:20  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:30  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:40  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:50  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:60  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:70  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:80  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:90  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:100  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:110  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:120  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:130  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:140  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:150  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:160  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:170  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:180  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:190  Accuracy =  0.03  Loss = nan
Training Step:200  Accuracy =  0.0275  Loss = nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for cross entropy is wrong. `neural_network_model(x)` does not return a probability distribution over the 62 classes. You can create a distribution by using `tf.nn.softmax` which uses the exponential function to make all the values positive.

`logits = neural_network_model(x)`

`predicted_probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)`

`cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(predicted_probabilities), reduction_indices=[1]))`

There is a potential problem with numerical stability due to using the exponential function inside the call to `tf.nn.softmax` followed by taking the log when computing the cross entropy. A much better way of doing it is to use the builtin softmax cross entropy functions in tensorflow.

Comment: `tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(` on some `predicted_probabilities` is always a bad idea! Use the built-in function for numerical stability (for the gradients). **Not** as an alternative. It should be the first choice!

Comment: @Patwie you're right about that. I'll edit my answer to include that info.

Answer (score -1):

@Aaron is already covering well the error regarding the numerical meaning of your loss, and why you should consider native Tensorflow losses such as `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy()`.

I will personally focus on "*why the NaNs?*".

---

#### Possible Reason:

As your weight and bias variables can take negative values, it is possible that your network output `out = tf.matmul(l3, output['weight'])+ output['bias']` becomes negative too. When it happens,  `tf.log(neural_network_model(x))` will output `NaN` (as the logarithm is undefined for null and negative values), and so will your `cross_entropy` loss.

Making sure your network output is positive (e.g. adding another `relu` or `softmax` + adding a small positive epsilon inside `tf.log()` e.g. `tf.log(out + 1e-8)`) may solve your problem.

---

#### Demonstration:

To make my point clear regarding your possibly-negative `y` and thus `tf.log(y) == NaN`, find below your slightly edited code. Besides some optimizations and input-mocking, your network architecture is the same. I only edited the initialization of the weights/bias of the last layer (in a dirty way...) to ensure `y >= 0`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

n_node_hl1 = 100
n_node_hl2 = 100
n_node_hl3 = 100
n_classes = 62
hidden_layer_1 = {'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4096, n_node_hl1])),
                    'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl1]))}
hidden_layer_2 = {'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl1, n_node_hl2])),
                    'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl2]))}
hidden_layer_3 = {'weight': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl2, n_node_hl3])),
                    'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl3]))}

# >>> CHANGE: MAKING SURE THE OUTPUT VARIABLES HAVE POSITIVE VALUES SO LOG(OUTPUT) != NaN
#             note: you do NOT want to do that! tf.abs() here are just to make my point.
output = {'weight': tf.Variable(tf.abs(tf.random_normal([n_node_hl3, n_classes]))),
            'bias': tf.Variable(tf.abs(tf.random_normal([n_classes])))}


def neural_network_model(data):
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_layer_1['weight']), hidden_layer_1['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_layer_2['weight']) , hidden_layer_2['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_layer_3['weight']) , hidden_layer_3['bias'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    out = tf.matmul(l3, output['weight'])+ output['bias']
    return out

# >>> CHANGE: MOCKING YOUR DATA:
x_train, y_train = np.random.rand(100, 4096), np.eye(n_classes)[np.random.randint(n_classes, size=100).reshape(-1)]
x_test, y_test = np.random.rand(50, 4096), np.eye(n_classes)[np.random.randint(n_classes, size=50).reshape(-1)]

with tf.name_scope("MNIST_Input"):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4096], name='x')
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 62], name='y')
y = neural_network_model(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.2
    TRAIN_STEPS = 200

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    with tf.name_scope("cross_entropy"):

# >>> CHANGE: REUSING "y" instead of re-instantiating the operations in "neural_network_model(x)":
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
    with tf.name_scope("loss_optimiser"):
        training = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cross_entropy)
    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    for i in range(TRAIN_STEPS+1):
        sess.run(training, feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train})
        if i%10 == 0:
            print('Training Step:' + str(i) + '  Accuracy =  ' + str(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test})) + '  Loss = ' + str(sess.run(cross_entropy, {x: x_train, y_: y_train})))
```

Trace:

```
Training Step:0  Accuracy =  0.04  Loss = -10.7876
Training Step:10  Accuracy =  0.04  Loss = -10.9636
Training Step:20  Accuracy =  0.04  Loss = -11.1214
Training Step:30  Accuracy =  0.04  Loss = -11.2649
Training Step:40  Accuracy =  0.04  Loss = -11.3968
Training Step:50  Accuracy =  0.04  Loss = -11.5175
Training Step:60  Accuracy =  0.04  Loss = -11.6284
Training Step:70  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -11.7313
Training Step:80  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -11.8277
Training Step:90  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -11.9183
Training Step:100  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.0041
Training Step:110  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.0853
Training Step:120  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.1625
Training Step:130  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.2359
Training Step:140  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.3058
Training Step:150  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.3725
Training Step:160  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.4363
Training Step:170  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.4973
Training Step:180  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.5558
Training Step:190  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.6121
Training Step:200  Accuracy =  0.02  Loss = -12.6662
```

... no `NaN`.

Comment: not really working. The same setup was working when i was training for digits.

Comment: hmm, the possibility for error is still there though, and it could be the previous training got lucky. Why not using e.g. `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy()`, at least to check if the error comes from your loss or not?